# How do I upload a photo to generate a PDF without storing the photo

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can ActiveStorage save a file in the session/browser to immediately use to render a PDF and then be forgotten?

Currently a user fills out a form, adds a photo and we store the photo in the cloud just to use once and then we delete the cloud photo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually need ActiveStorage just to [accept file uploads via a form](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#uploading-files):

```
<%= form_with(url: {action: :upload}, multipart: true) do %>
  <%= file_field_tag 'picture' %>
<% end %>
 
<%= form_with model: @person do |f| %>
  <%= f.file_field :picture %>
<% end %>
```

Submitting the form would give you an [ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.0.3.2/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/UploadedFile.html) instance in the parameters:

```
params[:picture]
params[:person][:picture]
```

This is really just a fancypants wrapper around a [Tempfile](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.3/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html) instance and thus it will unlink itself when rails is done with the request.

Whitelisting uploads is really easy since `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile` is one the permitted scalar types:

```
params.require(:person).permit(:picture)
```

The whole point of ActiveStorage really is not uploads - its providing a bunch of backends so that you can attach uploads to models and store them with a minimum of effort. If you're not storing the uploads its really just bloat.